# iOS 7 Bluetooth Output not working for AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, bluetooth

In my app, if iPhone is connected to Bluetooth headset, play sound with Bluetooth. Else use default speaker.

Here's my code

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

However, when I tried to use category setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord. Route to bluetooth device stopped working.. I don't know why. Because by right, the bluetooth option should only work for Record or PlayAndRecord category...

> /* only valid with AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord and AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord */

Addition: Can I have bluetooth for output ONLY (input still use default Mic from phone)?

**UPDATE**

I changed the order by calling setMode first, followed by setCategory. It works for the first time running the application (a call). When I tried to do the same action again, currentRoute still gave me output = Bluetooth but the actual output returns to default phone front speaker.

Comment: This helped me on a slightly different problem. Thank you!

Comment: Your question contained an answer for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been a while since I post this question and I kind forgot what exactly the problem is... If I remembered correctly it's due to another lib that kept rewriting the output route. somehow I fixed it and made it work the way I want.

I contributed the code to Jawbone's [AudioSessionManager](https://github.com/Jawbone/AudioSessionManager) lib. Hope that helps.